# Average a python dataframe column based on another column

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, average

I would like to take the average of column b when the corresponding value in column a is > 5

I get the error message:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03]

d = {'col_a': a, 'col_b': b}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

x = df['col_a' > 5]['col_b'].mean()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df['col_a' > 5]`

This tries to check if the string `'col_a'` is `> 5`, which can't be done.

You meant `df[df['col_a'] > 5]['col_b'].mean()`